# Link colour fills page

Tags: xetex, hyperref, ocgx2

This morning I updated my local MikTeX distribution with the pending package updates. I now get a completely blue page if the page contains a link, but only when compiled with XeLaTeX. Removing `ocgx2` makes the issue go away, but that's a package I need in my real life document.

What I don't understand is that neither `ocgx2` nor `hyperref` were updated this morning, according to the package manager they were installed early and late january, respectively.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}
\begin{document}
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{link}
\end{document}
```

Result before the updates, and after the updates when compiled with LaTeX:

[image: desired output]

Result after the updates, when compiled with XeLaTeX:

[image: blue page]

Output of `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
hyperref.sty    2020/01/14 v7.00d Hypertext links for LaTeX
 ltxcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   iftex.sty    2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests
pdftexcmds.sty    2019/11/24 v0.31 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2020/01/14 v7.00d Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2019/12/05 v1.19 At begin shipout hook (HO)
  hxetex.def    2020/01/14 v7.00d Hyperref driver for XeTeX
   puenc.def    2020/01/14 v7.00d Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
atveryend.sty    2019-12-11 v1.11 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
   ocgx2.sty    2019/11/07 v0.48 ports `ocgx' functionality to dvips+ps2pdf, xelatex and dvipdfmx
  xparse.sty    2020-02-25 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2020-02-25 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def    2020-02-23 L3 backend support: xdvipdfmx
l3keys2e.sty    2020-02-25 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
 ocgbase.sty    2019/11/04 v0.17 support package for ocgx2.sty
 pdfbase.sty    2020/01/27 v0.36 driver independent access to low-level PDF features
  ts1cmr.fd    2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
   color.sty    2019/11/23 v1.2a Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   xetex.def    2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
 nameref.sty    2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty    2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
    href.out
    href.out
se-ascii-print.def    2019/11/29 v1.12 stringenc: Printable ASCII characters
 ***********
```

Comment: it's OK in texlive updated a minute ago, so it's possibly more likely an issue with the xetex or xdvipdfmx binary than the latex packages. See if other miktex users can reproduce the problem (I don't have miktex, sorry)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is it really okay for you? I see it too. But only with xelatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes:  generated with cygwin xelatex, checked pdf in cygwin xpdf and windows acrobat (you have my pdf by email:-)

Comment: Had a look at some of the packages. `ocgx2` loads `ocgxbase`, which in turn loads `pdfbase`. And that last one _was_ amongst the files updated this morning ... unfortunately I don't have access to a previous version of it to check though.

Comment: No, it is probably not a package problem but a problem with xdvipdfmx.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am compiling the TeXLive svn version of xdvipdfmx (20200116) right now, to have the same version here as in MiKTeX. Then I will run a test.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Bummer! There is an issue with the current xdvipdfmx (2020-01-16). I can confirm the reported behaviour.

Comment: @takrl we know why it happens, but it will probably require an new xdvipdfmx to get around the issue. For now you can't use the  ocgcolorlinks option of ocgx2 with xelatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer & AlexG Thanks for your efforts in tracking this down, good to know you identified the root component causing this issue. I assume it'll take a little while for a fix to be built, and then to populate through to the MikTeX repositories ... for the time being, I'll simply not update my second MikTeX on my machine at home.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do I need to report this anywhere else, ie. github & friends, to get it fixed? I don't really know where the codebase for this component resides, or by whom it's maintained ...

Comment: xdvipdfmx has been corrected, in texlive 2020 (pretest has just begun) the problem is already gone. miktex will probably catch up soon, if not you could open an issue there. The discussion about the problem is here: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2020-February/044855.html

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, I just added an [issue for MiKTeX](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/489) ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. In the meantime, the `xdvipdfmx` binary was updated to its current version across all TeX distributions, including [MiKTeX](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/489), which resolves the issue described here.

Comment: @AlexG You beat me to it by a few hours, I noticed this afternoon that it works again after the latest update. Thanks ...